# Fill function constructor depending on objects/strings in array

Tags: php

I have array with strings/objects I want to use in function

```
$args = ['hello', $object];
```

Now I'm using call_user_func to execute static function from my second class.

```
call_user_func([Handler::class, 'func']);
```

This code throw error because function 'func' require 2 parameters in it's constructor, but it's empty
So i want to make it look like this

```
call_user_func([Handler::class, 'func'], 'hello', $object);
```

Array $args can be of different amount of strings/objects inside.

Comment: try `call_user_func_array`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 2):

The function you should be using is `call_user_func_array()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

> mixed call_user_func_array ( callable $callback , array $param_arr )
>   Calls the callback given by the first parameter with the parameters in param_arr.

So in your case:

```
call_user_func_array([Handler::class, 'func'], ['hello', $object]);
```

Where `hello` is the first argument, and `$object` is the second.

The advantage of this is `$param_arr` can be variable in length, where as the arguments in `call_user_func` have to be entered 1 by 1 so they are a fixed length.  Which is exactly what you want `Array $args can be of different amount of strings/objects inside.`

So just replace `$param_arr` with your `$args` array and you are all set.